# Mule Devkit 3.6 custom connector @Text annotation not working fine

Tags: mule, mule-studio, mule-component

As per the documentation @Text should generate a child element in the editors.xml of the plugin and a text box in the GUI. teh 3.6.0 devkit maven stuff is not generating this correctly. it genrates a string element in editors.xml 
Seems like 3.6.1-SNAPSHOT is generating the editors.xml fine. Its generating text element but there is no childElement in xml. Am attaching the Xml and te connector code for verification. Need directions here please.

```
@Configurable
@Summary("Main file documentation explaining what the impex file contains.")
@Placement(tab = "Impex Details", order = 1)
@Optional
@Text
private String impexFileMainDocumentation;

@Configurable
@Summary("Impex Locale")
@Placement(tab = "Impex Details", order = 2)
@Required
private String impexLocale;

@Configurable
@Summary("Impex Macro Definitions if any. One Macro on one line.")
@Placement(tab = "Impex Details", order = 3)
@Optional
@Text
private String impexFileMacros;
```

And the XML generated as this:

```
<group id="general" caption="General">
    <string name="targetLocation" caption="Target Location" description="The file system location where the Impex file will be generated." required="true" javaType="java.lang.String"></string>
    <text isToElement="true" wrapWithCDATA="true" name="impexFileMainDocumentation" caption="Impex file main documentation" visibleInDialog="true" required="false"></text>
    <string name="impexLocale" caption="Impex Locale" description="Impex Locale." required="true" javaType="java.lang.String"></string>
  </group>
```

Answer (score 1):

this is a known issue with the latest Devkit. Devkit 3.6.1 should contain the fix. HTH.

Comment: No it doesn't have it. I build with 3.6.1-SNAPSHOT in my connector project pom and it can understand the @Text annotation. But generation is still wrong. I get the editors.xml as the one I posted in my question. Is there an alternative or workaround for this?

Comment: That is just a snapshot build. The fix should be in the final version which should be released soon.

Comment: Okie sure. I will wait for that. But its disheartening you know. Mule was such a lovely open source project with such perfect working. Its getting ruined with this enterprise and community thing.

Answer (score 0):

@Text does not work at @Configurable level, you should use it at @Processor parameter level